# How to horizontally centre align image frame with of text frame in Adobe Muse for responsive design?

Tags: alignment, snapping, adobe-muse

I currently have an image and text both horizontally centre aligned, and I have set both to be responsive.

When I change the width of the browser, the text pushes down, but the image is still top aligned. Is there a way to horizontal centre pin the image to the text so that the image moves as the text pushes down?

Original:

[image: Original]

Shrink width:

[image: shrink]

Ideal:

[image: ideal]

Answer (score 0):

Group the objects together and then pin them

Comment: This answer is really short. Is there anything you can add to it?